# Why isn't Saudi Arabia running after Nuclear Weapons?

Tags: nuclear-weapons, saudi-arabia

Iran clearly desires to have Nuclear weapons, so does North Korea. Possession of Nuclear Weapon deters an enemy on engaging a war. Why isn't Saudi Arabia which has the third largest Military Budget desire Nuclear Weapons?

Comment: I am not sure if it is a good question. Having a large budget doesn't mean nuclear weapons is sought after. This question also seems to be politically motivated.

Comment: Saudi Arabia is in the midst of a [huge budget crisis](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/jan/06/eleven-saudi-princes-detained-after-protesting-about-loss-of-perks) because of low oil prices, and has no economy to speak of outside of oil exports. Also, as a US lapdog\b\b\b\b\b\b ally it already has a _de facto_ arsenal.

Comment: Additionally, Saudi Arabia has been a very strong financier of Pakistan's nuclear program. There have been recurring accusations that they've transferred know how and technology necessary for a weapons program.

Comment: @janh why don't they develop one themselves?

Comment: I can only speculate, but co-financing somebody else's would be considerably cheaper, and not officially seeking nuclear weapons is politically more opportune when dealing with western countries.

Comment: Because the predicted value of US umbrella exceeds the predicted  value of DIY approach in KSA government's mind. Which may not necessarily be a valid calculation at this point, considering what happened to Ukraine.

Comment: How do you know they don't already have a few? They certainly have the money, and have been rumored to have financed a good deal of the Pakistan nukes... perhaps the price of that financial assistance was a few bombs. They could be doing what Israel did: build nukes, but keep it secret for reasons of plausible deniability. If SA (or Israel) openly boasted about having nuclear weapons, it would cause their neighbors to redouble their efforts to get them.

Comment: "Why" questions are really hard to answer, because they require knowledge of the inner workings of people's heads or closed government meetings.  If this question were reworked to ask "What stops Saudia Arabia from acquiring nuclear weapons?" or something like that, it would be worth reopening.

Comment: One reason might be that nukes have mostly come to be about defense but the Saudi Arabian armament is about offense.

Comment: I wouldn't be too sure they aren't. This might be just for civillian purposes, but who knows? https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-01-15/saudi-arabia-seen-awarding-nuclear-reactor-contracts-in-december

Answer (score 4):

Good question.

Several reasons come in my mind:

1. Saudis know that the USA won't tolerate any nuclear country in the proximity of Israel. Saddam and Gaddafi tried and fell victim of US rage. Iran is trying or tried in futility.
2. Saudis are actually under US protection. Going nuclear will create trust deficit and will call the demise of monarchy which the house of sauds are scared of.
3. Finally, it is speculated that Saudis financed Pakistani nuclear program and Pakistan is ready to ship nuclear weapon to Saudis at any moment and on demand.